# XSLT: Compare two files and list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to compare two xml files:

```
$ cat input.xml
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" >
  <outer param="p1" >
   <inner />
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer >
   <inner />
  </outer>
  <outer />
  <outer />
 </section>
 <section id="2" >
  <outer >
   <inner />
   <inner />
   <inner />
  </outer>
 </section>
 <section id="3" >
  <outer >
   <inner />
  </outer>
 </section>
 <section id="7" >
  <outer >
   <inner />
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

The other file is:

```
$ cat result.xml 
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" status="fail">
  <outer param="p1" status="fail">
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass">
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass"/>
  <outer status="fail"/>
 </section>
 <section id="2" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="pass"/>
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="inc"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
 <section id="5" status="pass">
  <outer status="pass">
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
 <section id="6" status="inc">
  <outer status="inc">
   <inner status="inc"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

I want to print the `<section>` nodes from `input.xml` that are not in `result.xml`. The nodes can be uniquely identified by their `id` attribute.
I have tried this XSLT file:

```
$ cat missing.xsl 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="doc" select="document('result.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:variable name="var" select="$doc/rootnode/section" />
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//section/@id[not(. = $var/@id)] ">
            <missing><xsl:value-of select="."/></missing>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, however, only return the id-values. I need the whole section node.
Am I simply using a wrong xpath in `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` or is my approach fundamentally flawed?

PS: The solution should be in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently selecting the `@id` attribute, not the `section` element itself, so `xsl:value-of` will just get the value of that attribute.

Just change your `select` expression to select `section` elements and move the `@id` into the condition

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//section[not(@id = $var/@id)] ">
        <missing><xsl:copy-of select="."/></missing>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Note the use of `xsl:copy-of` to copy the `section` element too. `xsl:value-of` is used to get the string value of a node, not the node itself.